# Package "Kendall" in R- Version 3.1.1

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me how to install "Kendall" package in R 3.1.1 version.

I have been trying to install using

install.packages("Kendall")

but everytime I do this, I get an error:

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Kendall’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

Comment: Have you looked at: [How should I deal with “package 'xxx' is not available” warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-warning)?? If so, describe what you've already tried.

Comment: Hi, I looked into this. I tried setting the repositories and finding the package in each but it was not available.

Comment: I installed it just fine on R 3.1.1 on windows 7 using CRAN.wustl.edu. How about including your OS and seasionInfo() information. Can you install other packages?

Comment: Yes I can install other packages!

Comment: I also have windows 7 enterprise